# Union of 20 datasets always OOMs the Spark driver

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a fairly simple spark job that just unions a bunch of datasets. The code is roughly the following:

```
List<Dataset<Row>> inputs; // about 20 input datasets
Dataset<Row> output = inputs.stream().reduce(Dataset::union).map(ds -> ds.repartition(600)) 
writeToHDFS(output)
```

When I run this and look at the job in YARN I can see that it is all executed on the driver. (there aren't any filters or calculations to be done here).

However, when I start the job I can see that it starts doing something until it does a FULL GC and the gets killed by YARN after about 2 minutes after it started.

All input datasets are fairly small (between 1GB and 20GB) and I'm already running it with the following spark config:

```
spark.driver.cores: 8
spark.driver.memory: 28g
```

Do you guys have any other idea how I can make the union succeed? Can this be distributed somehow so that it doesn't OOM the driver?

I've used the writeToHDFS function (custom code) with datasets that are TBs big and had no issue, so I doubt its the storing piece. It's more the serialization that is normally probably reading the results from the executors but in the case of the `union` trying to assemble the entire piece in the driver.

Comment: How do you create `inputs`?

Comment: the inputs are all `Dataset<Row>` that are read from HDFS and created from there. I can do any operation on them so reading them in works fine. I can also access the spark context of them if that helps.

Comment: What version of Spark are you running?  In the past there have been bugs around `union` with Spark.

Comment: Since you know that the size of your datasets is quite small I don't see the reason why to repartition them before the union. Also I would check the partition number of output dataframe and possibly try to repartition this one instead.